# simple functions are in Lp

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space. For $\displaystyle f=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j1_{E_j}$ where $\mu(E_j),n<\infty$ for all $j$. Clearly, $f\in L_p(X,M,\mu)$.

I guess this is trivial for most people, but I just want to make sure if I am understanding this correctly.

So the reasoning I think is that, we have $\displaystyle||f||^p_p=\int\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{E_j}\right|^p\mathrm{d}\mu$ since $\{E_j\}$ are pairwise disjoint, we must have $\displaystyle\int\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j1_{E_j}\right|^p\mathrm{d}\mu=\int\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^p1_{E_j}\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^p\mu(E_j)<\infty$. Since $n<\infty$ and $\mu(E_j)<\infty$.

Do I have correct idea?
Thanks!

Comment: This is correct for $p$ finite. $p=+\infty$ needs to be handled separately, which is trivial since $\max\{|a_i| :1\le i\le n\}+1$ is an essential upper bound.